# How to configure an HTTP Server in front of WAS cluster?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have defined a Websphere 8.5 cluster made up of two Nodes, now I'd like to put an HTTP Server in front of the cluster which balances calls. When I add a new Web Server from the console, I'm allowed to choose **either** Node1 or Node2, but I'd like provide an array of Nodes. 
Coming from a Tomcat MOD_JK background, I used to do that so that the balancer choose which node will server the call. 
Should I manually edit the configuration and add a reference to all Nodes (how?) ?
Thanks
Louis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from experience with earlier versions of WebSphere, you define multiple such Web Servers. That is, define one for Node1, then a second one for Node2.

Then when you deploy your application, select both the Application Server Cluster you want to deploy it to and **all** the Web Servers you want to participate in that cluster.

If you do this, the WebSphere plugin running under each of the Web Servers will maintain Session affinity by routing the user to the same Cluster member as long as it's available. See http://ibm.co/S2UKKn and http://ibm.co/QIs0Sg .

To actually use multiple Web Servers, you will of course still need some kind of IP load balancer or sprayer. The WebSphere product family has one in its Edge Components ( https://ibm.biz/BdxZwg ), but there are many such software products or hardware devices.

Comment: I am working from memory too, we woudl define web servers. These are independent of the App Server hosting nodes and when you deploy an application you would state the target to include the Cluster and the Web Server. This allows the web server to create the appropriate plugin which is then copied (either automatically or manually) to the Web Server which in turn does the load balancing.  I am not sure i follow what you mean by defining web server for Node 1 and Node2. We will simply need to create one or more web servers in the WAS topology.

Comment: Thanks for your replies: what I really mean is that if I need to create two Web servers, let's say WebServer1 for Node1 and WebServer2 for Node 2, which is then the address that I provide to the client (WebServer1 or WebServer2) ? I would need to put another Webserver to balance calls between the two Web servers. I'd expect rather to provide to the client the Cluster Web address and then the  Web server will do load balancing between the Application Servers....

Comment: You don't provide the end user an address of either of the Web Servers, you provide a dispatched address/DNS name which would be sprayed between the two Web Servers. And you might have to add that dispatched address to the WebSphere Virtual Host alias list. You're correct that if you have multiple Web Servers, *something* has to be dispatching between them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. So the final question is: which is the component that actually spread the requests between Web servers ?mapping a virtual address with a set of DNS entries is the simplest choice but it won't allow sticky session (I think). So I'm looking for *where* do I configure in WAS or IBM HTTP Server to spread the load between WebServer1 and WebServer2. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you deploy your application to a Cluster and to multiple Web Servers, the Web Server plugin will maintain session affinity. It does this via specific portions of the Session ID cookie. See http://ibm.co/S2UKKn and http://ibm.co/QIs0Sg

Comment: Oh, and to spread the request between Web Servers, you need some kind of IP load balancer. The WebSphere product family has one in its Edge Components ( http://bit.ly/Os3l8L ), but there are many such devices.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new unmanaged node and store the web server configuration in there. When you regenerate the plugin config file, it will be placed in the unmanaged node's configuration directory and you can then copy the new config file into the correct directory for the web server plugin. This is the standard approach, which is described in detail in [this draft redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg248056.html?Open) (chapters 13 and 16)